# Странное поведение при подключении заголовка

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cocos2d

Есть один заголовок, вот с таким содержимым

```
#pragma once

#include "Unit.h"

#include <memory>

class TankModel: public Unit
{
public:
    TankModel();
    ~TankModel();

    void thrust(float deltaTime);
    void backing(float deltaTime);
    void rotateLeft(float deltaTime);
    void rotateRight(float deltaTime);
    void shoot(float deltaTime);

private:
    const float moveSpeed;
    const float rotationSpeed;
};
```

и есть второй с таким содержимым

```
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <memory>

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "TankModel.h"
#include "TankView.h"
#include "TankController.h"

USING_NS_CC;

class GameScene : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    static Scene* createScene();
    virtual bool init();
    CREATE_FUNC(GameScene);
    void update(float) override;

private:

    void onKeyPressed(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event) override;
    void onKeyReleased(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event) override;

    bool isKeyDown(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode);

    std::map<EventKeyboard::KeyCode, bool> keys;

    std::shared_ptr<TankModel> tankModel;
    std::shared_ptr<TankController> tankController;
    TankView* tankView;
};
```

При таком раскладе все успешно собирается и компилируется.

Но я хочу прокинуть в **TankModel** **GameScene**. И стоит мне добавить заголовок **TankModel.h** строку `#include "GameScene.h"` все тут же перестает работать.

`#pragma once` как видно везде есть, но это не помогает.

Ошибка вылезает `'TankModel': undeclared identifier (compiling source file TankView.cpp)` и указывает на определение переменной типа **TankModel**.

Я если честно, вообще не понимаю в чем проблема.

Comment: Старайтесь выносить инклуды в cpp файлы, а для указателей/ссылок в хэдерах использовать forward declaration. Тогда не придется отлаживать подобные проблемы.

Comment: А зачем вам `GameScene.h` включать в `TankModel`, вы же сцену там не используете?

Comment: Но, насколько я понимаю, я не могу унести инклюды в cpp, потому что заголовках есть объявления объектов-членов. Если перенести и их в cpp как есть, то они попадут в глобальную область видимости.

Comment: Сейчас я не использую там сцену как раз из-за того, что я не смогу подключить нормально заголовок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас при чтении `TankModel.h` в результате сначала читается `GameScene.h`, в нем указано включение `TankView.h` и `TankController.h`, которые начинают читаться и в которых, очевидно, есть ссылки на `class TankModel`, но до определения этого класса дело ведь еще не дошло...

Грубо говоря, вы поставили телегу - которая ссылается на лошадь - перед лошадью.

Какой вообще смысл в таком включении `GameScene.h` в `TankModel.h`?

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ! Да, я понимаю, что у меня циклическое ссылка в заголовочных файлах, но разве #pragma once не должна решать эту проблему?  Мне необходимо вызывать метод сцены, который будет класть на нее объект пульки.

Comment: Конечно же нет! `#pragma once` решает вопрос с **повторным включением**, а не зацикливанием. Переформулируйте свой вопрос в терминах классов и методов, потому что для меня "медод сцены для пульки", например, ничего не говорит.

Comment: Есть объект `GameScene`, который должен содержать все объекты `GameObject` (наследниками которого являются `TankModel` и `BulletModel`) и обеспечивать их взаимодействие, такое как обновление координат, обработка столкновений и пр. Объект `TankModel` имеет метод `shoot()` который должен создавать новый экземпляр `BulletModel` и отдавать его объекту `GameScene` для его обработки. Соответственно, мне, внутри `TankModel` необходимо получить указатель на объект `GameScene`, чтобы передать ему в методе созданный объект. То есть выполнить что-то вроде `gameScene->addBullet(bullet)`.

Comment: Добавьте перед `class TankModel: public Unit` строчку `class GameScene;`

Comment: Да, есть, спасибо!